# couchdb on ssl runs with error

Tags: ssl, couchdb

I can see couch db running on port `5984` and `6984` using

```
sudo lsof -i :5984
```

and

```
sudo lsof -i :6984
```

However, when I access it through the browser, I get the error shared at bottom of post. I will need to access this through pouch db running from an application running on `SSL`.

In local.ini, I have this:

```
[ssl]
cert_file = /home/ec2-user/api_aonesalons_com.crt
key_file = /home/ec2-user/myserver.key
```

error when accessed on https.

```
[error] [<0.392.0>] {error_report,<0.62.0>,
                                  {<0.392.0>,std_error,
                                   [83,83,76,58,32,"1112",58,32,"error",58,
                                    "[]",32,"/home/ec2-user/myserver.key",
                                    "\n",32,32,
                                    [91,
                                     [[123,
                                       ["ssl_connection",44,
                                        "init_private_key",44,"5"],
                                       125],
                                      44,10,"   ",
                                      [123,
                                       ["ssl_connection",44,"ssl_init",44,"2"],
                                       125],
                                      44,10,"   ",
                                      [123,
                                       ["ssl_connection",44,"init",44,"1"],
                                       125],
                                      44,10,"   ",
                                      [123,
                                       ["gen_fsm",44,"init_it",44,"6"],
                                       125],
                                      44,10,"   ",
                                      [123,
                                       ["proc_lib",44,"init_p_do_apply",44,
                                        "3"],
                                       125]],
                                     93],
                                    "\n"]}}

=ERROR REPORT==== 8-Feb-2018::15:40:11 ===
SSL: 1112: error:[] /home/ec2-user/myserver.key
  [{ssl_connection,init_private_key,5},
   {ssl_connection,ssl_init,2},
   {ssl_connection,init,1},
   {gen_fsm,init_it,6},
   {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]

[error] [<0.392.0>] {error_report,<0.62.0>,
                        {<0.392.0>,crash_report,
                         [[{initial_call,
                               {ssl_connection,init,['Argument__1']}},
                           {pid,<0.392.0>},
                           {registered_name,[]},
                           {error_info,
                               {exit,ekeyfile,
                                   [{gen_fsm,init_it,6},
                                    {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},
                           {ancestors,[ssl_connection_sup,ssl_sup,<0.63.0>]},
                           {messages,[]},
                           {links,[<0.67.0>]},
                           {dictionary,[]},
                           {trap_exit,false},
                           {status,running},
                           {heap_size,1597},
                           {stack_size,24},
                           {reductions,1169}],
                          []]}}

=CRASH REPORT==== 8-Feb-2018::15:40:11 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: ssl_connection:init/1
    pid: <0.392.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: ekeyfile
      in function  gen_fsm:init_it/6
    ancestors: [ssl_connection_sup,ssl_sup,<0.63.0>]
    messages: []
    links: [<0.67.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: false
    status: running
    heap_size: 1597
    stack_size: 24
    reductions: 1169
  neighbours:
[error] [<0.67.0>] {error_report,<0.62.0>,
                       {<0.67.0>,supervisor_report,
                        [{supervisor,{local,ssl_connection_sup}},
                         {errorContext,child_terminated},
                         {reason,ekeyfile},
                         {offender,
                             [{pid,<0.392.0>},
                              {name,undefined},
                              {mfargs,{ssl_connection,start_link,undefined}},
                              {restart_type,temporary},
                              {shutdown,4000},
                              {child_type,worker}]}]}}

=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 8-Feb-2018::15:40:11 ===
     Supervisor: {local,ssl_connection_sup}
     Context:    child_terminated
     Reason:     ekeyfile
     Offender:   [{pid,<0.392.0>},
                  {name,undefined},
                  {mfargs,{ssl_connection,start_link,undefined}},
                  {restart_type,temporary},
                  {shutdown,4000},
                  {child_type,worker}]

[error] [<0.180.0>] {error_report,<0.31.0>,
                                  {<0.180.0>,std_error,
                                   [{application,mochiweb},
                                    "Accept failed error",
                                    "{error,ekeyfile}"]}}

=ERROR REPORT==== 8-Feb-2018::15:40:11 ===
    application: mochiweb
    "Accept failed error"
    "{error,ekeyfile}"
[error] [<0.180.0>] {error_report,<0.31.0>,
                        {<0.180.0>,crash_report,
                         [[{initial_call,
                               {mochiweb_acceptor,init,
                                   ['Argument__1','Argument__2',
                                    'Argument__3']}},
                           {pid,<0.180.0>},
                           {registered_name,[]},
                           {error_info,
                               {exit,
                                   {error,accept_failed},
                                   [{mochiweb_acceptor,init,3},
                                    {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},
                           {ancestors,
                               [https,couch_secondary_services,
                                couch_server_sup,<0.32.0>]},
                           {messages,[]},
                           {links,[<0.146.0>,#Port<0.3466>]},
                           {dictionary,[]},
                           {trap_exit,false},
                           {status,running},
                           {heap_size,987},
                           {stack_size,24},
                           {reductions,18123}],
                          []]}}

=CRASH REPORT==== 8-Feb-2018::15:40:11 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: mochiweb_acceptor:init/3
    pid: <0.180.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {error,accept_failed}
      in function  mochiweb_acceptor:init/3
    ancestors: [https,couch_secondary_services,couch_server_sup,<0.32.0>]
    messages: []
    links: [<0.146.0>,#Port<0.3466>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: false
    status: running
    heap_size: 987
    stack_size: 24
    reductions: 18123
  neighbours:
[error] [<0.146.0>] {error_report,<0.31.0>,
                        {<0.146.0>,std_error,
                         {mochiweb_socket_server,297,
                             {acceptor_error,{error,accept_failed}}}}}

=ERROR REPORT==== 8-Feb-2018::15:40:11 ===
{mochiweb_socket_server,297,{acceptor_error,{error,accept_failed}}}
```

SSL certificate used here works just fine with apache so should not really be a problem.
I am facing this issue same as described here
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/couchdb-user-archive/Jlqfj-8a_sM

Comment: @Flimzy: I have posted it in question only.couchdb on ssl runs with error for ssl file not included in config

=INFO REPORT==== 8-Feb-2018::12:37:45 ===
[error] [<0.1147.0>] {error_report,<0.62.0>,
                                   {<0.1147.0>,std_error,
                                    [83,83,76,58,32,"1112",58,32,"error",58,
                                     "[]",32,
                                     "/home/ec2-user/aonesalons.com.key","\n",

Comment: In Fauxton, are the paths stored in the ssl section of the config panel the right ones?

Comment: I believe they are stored in local.ini, is that correct? I have edited that and posted it in the question itself.

Comment: Couchdb can have read/write permission issue, or it may not be configured to read from it at all, or something else entirely.

Comment: You mean the key file that I am passing? Possible. How do I check if couchdb has permission to access the file?

Comment: By checking in fauxton. If the ssl section is the same as your local.ini. By the way, When you use the http api to change settings (curl, fauxton, etc), they are automatically applied, but if you directly modify the file, you have to restart couchdb. Couchdb doesn't detect filesystem changes.

Comment: Yes, I am restarting couch db properly. I can assure that. Also, I have checked in fauxton. It also uses : cert_file 
/home/ec2-user/api_aonesalons_com.crt
x
key_file 
/home/ec2-user/myserver.key